# Linq List to Byte Array

Tags: linq, csv, asp.net-core

I search in google, stackoverflow but did not get easy answer. Is there any way to convert a linq list to byte array?

```
public FileResult GetCustomerListCSV()
{
  List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();
  CustomerList = dbContext.Customer.ToList(); // Need to convert this into byte array
  return File(CustomerList, "text/csv", "CustomerList.csv");
}
```

Please help.

Comment: This seems a bit weird as requirement. Can you explain what you want to do with a List of Customers transformed in a byte array?

Comment: I want to download as csv file.

Comment: Better use specific libraries that creates a CSV file for you both in memory or disk

Comment: .Net core will automatically create csv but I need to convert linq list to byte array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a CSV string first, then convert it to bytes:

```
var lines = CustomerList.Select(c => $"{c.Id}, {c.Name}");
var csv = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);
return File(bytes, "text/csv", "CustomerList.csv");
```

Alternatively, using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library:

```
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        
csv.WriteRecords(CustomerList);
csv.Flush();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(ms, "text/csv", "CustomerList.csv");
```